# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on AWS Elastic Beanstalk load balancer with additional mod_rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, mod-rewrite

I have a web app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and SSL is working, but I need to make sure all the traffic is HTTPS. I think there is a conflict with our existing rules, or the load balancer. Here are the rules from our .htaccess file:

    RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !uploads
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css¦js|html|png|xml|mp3|m4a)
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/uploads/users/avatar/$ /images/default-user.jpg

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} uploads
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /api/index.php/media/load?fileKey=$3 [QSA,L]

#force https
#RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
#RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```

The http part is commented out. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I tried it. It's giving me the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS thing again

Comment: Are the rules you put on the question the only ones?

Comment: yes, but this is a server running behind and AWS load balancer. The version that is commented out is the recommended solution.